# Karabiner Elements: Map Sequence of Keys (Multiple) to Sequence of Keys

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am [using a US International Keyboard on Windows](https://resources.german.lsa.umich.edu/schreiben/umlaute/) to easily type special characters by combining (=consecutively typing) single quotes / double quotes and vowels to get German umlaute characters.

For instance, to get umlaut Ü: `"`, `U` 
Whereas to get double quotes: `"`, `[space]`

On MacOS, I have tried to use [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) to emulate this behaviour.

However, while one can easily map a single key stroke to multiple characters (`f`>`f`,`o`,`o`), the reverse is not as well documented.
[It is possible to map a combination of modifier keys and character keys](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377256/using-karabiner-for-multi-key-to-multi-key-remapping) (`[fn]`, `U`).

However, in order to emulate the behaviour of my Windows US International keyboard, I would need to map a sequence of keys (`"`, `U` > `Ü` and `"`, `[space]` > `"`).

**How can I map a sequence of keys to another sequence of keys in Karabiner Elements?**

Comment: Why don't you want to do it the native Mac way - which is considerably simpler than the Windows method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm parking this answer here as a frame challenge…*

Why not do it the native Mac way - which is considerably simpler than the Windows method?

The Mac has a series of *dead-keys* which you can see marked orange in the keyboard viewer if you press Opt

[image]

From this you can see that the Umlaut dead-key is U.
If you want to add an umlaut to any letter [only regularly-supported letters, you can't add one to a Z this way, just the usual ä ë ï ö ü] you hit  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>U</kbd>  then the letter to be accented, ie U itself. This gives ü with two keypresses.

If you just want a double quote, just type a double quote,  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>'</kbd>  which gives " - & no hoops to jump.

There's none of that awkward having to remember that a key can be 'smart' & you have to add a space if you don't want it to be 'smart'.
IMO, this is definitely *'not smart'*.

Answer (score 0):

Use Karabiner to map one of your keys to <kbd>F15</kbd>. Then create `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` with the appropriate sequence definition from https://github.com/noel-yap/KeyBindings/blob/main/DefaultKeyBinding.dict, eg:

```
{
    "\UF712" = {
        "\U0022" = {
            "\U0075" = ("insertText:", "\U00FC"); /* F15, QUOTATION MARK, LATIN SMALL LETTER U: LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS */
        };
    };
}
```

Note that not all apps (eg JetBrains products) abide by the above although many do.

It's also possible to map key sequences with Karabiner but that's more difficult involving variables to maintain state. OTOH, using Karabiner to define key combinations with modifiers (eg <kbd>⎇</kbd>) is easier.